# is it possible to two way bind to a published object on an observableObject (not observed object)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I of course can use an observedobject to bind in two ways to my screen like normal - suppose my object is

```swift
struct MyView
{
    @ObservedObject var stuff = MyObject()
    var body: some View { TextField( text=$stuff.value )}
}

class MyObject : ObservableObject
{
    @Published var value: String = "some value"
}
```

So binding *up* from myObject is trivial.

I also want to bind bidirectionally *down*.  I am trying to build a generic persistence layer which stores data in user defaults, transfers stuff through to the watch, logs - so what I want to do is change MyObject so that it looks like something like this:

```swift
class MyObject : ObservableObject
{
    @Published var value: String = "some value"

    init()
    {
        Storage.shared.bind("value", $value );
    }
}
```

Which I'm hoping will achieve a two-way binding - for instance if someone sets something on the watch - events will come through that the persisted value has changed, and that should set this value, which will in turn set the UI value.

The problem comes when I try to implement the bind function - because that basically leaves me with this signature:

```swift
class Storage
{
    public static let shared = Storage()

    func bind( key : string, publisher: Published<String>.Publisher)
    ...
}
```

Which gives me all sorts of ways to subscribe to the value changing - I can easily see in the storage layer if the value has changed somewhere else, and write it into user defaults etc - but it gives me no (that I can tell) of *setting* the value from the storage layer.  - e.g. if someone changes it on the watch, I get an event in the storage layer, I read out the new value, I need to be able to set it.

I then tried this:

```swift
    @ObservedObject let this = self;
    Storage.shared.bind("value", $this.value );
```

Which gives me a Binding - which I guess in theory is bidirectional, but I couldn't figure out how to do anything with it at all.  I can find tons of information about *producing* a binding object, but everything assumes you are going to use it in the UI - I can't find any information anywhere about consuming or using a binding yourself.

I have a number of objects and lots of properties, so if I can get this generic linkage working, it will save me a ridiculous amount of code.

Comment: `class MyView` -- `View` in SwiftUi shouldn't be a `class`. `class MyObject` should be an `ObservableObject`.

Comment: Binding is for SwiftUI views it depends on the body for updated values because of its DynamicProperty inheritance.

Comment: It is best to show a minimal reproducible code, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . 
Currently you have: 
 `TextField( text=$stuff.value )` and many other mistakes in your code example, which leads me to believe
  it is just a made-up code that does not represents the issue. Show the code you have tried and the errors you get.

Comment: Just curious why you don't want to use `AppStorage`? It is a built in property wrapper for user defaults and can be used in SwiftUI to observe changes

Comment: If you wanted to actually build it yourself (IMHO AppStorage already exists) you should use a KeyPath as the parameter not a publisher. Then your custom type should publish any changes. All this is readily available via AppStorage

Comment: because appstorage doesn't mirror stuff across to the watch - but I think it's the better track - I've basically built a property wrapper like appstorage - that shares all its changes with the watch